# Insterting setInterval inside a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, setinterval

I'm having trouble inserting setInterval inside a for loop. I want the words from an array to be displayed one at a time in a div with a delay of 1 second(variable). Currently, it only displays the last word of the array after a delay of 1 second.

```
var words = input.split(/[ \t\n]+/);
var temp = 0;
for(var i=0; i<words.length ;i++) {
    setInterval(function() {document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = words[temp];
        temp++;},1000);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";}
```

Comment: Beside all, why are you using `temp` variable instead of using `i` directly for array index number? It will do the same thing as far as i can see.

Comment: @Litestone Closures. `i` will equal `words.length` at the point in time where `words[i]` would be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the interval to happen `words.length` times, all at the 1-second mark after the loop has run. The result: all the words are shown one after another in the same frame, leaving just the last one.

I would suggest a different approach.

```
var words = input.split(/\s+/); // "any whitespace"
function nextWord() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = words.shift();
    if( words.length > 0) setTimeout(nextWord,1000);
    else alert("Done!"); // you can do something else here
}
setTimeout(nextWord,1000);
// or just call nextWord() if you want the first word to appear immediately.
```

This works its way through your string until there are no words left.

Comment: How would I accomplish the same result using setInterval?

Comment: Something like `var interval = setInterval(nextWord,1000);` to start it, then inside the function replace the `if( words.length > 0) setTimeout...` bit with `if( words.length == 0) clearInterval(interval);`